# Modelica Dymola half vehicle modeling connection errors

Tags: modelica, dymola

I (beginner) am using dymola to model half  rail vehicle dynamic system for vehicle and pitch motions.

The model has only wheels, bogies, car body and spring-damper connections without inputs and prismatic joints. I only need vertical motion of each body and pitch of the Carbody w.r.t time. Although last variation has no errors, system is going down. What should I do? And I have the vertical track irregularity file as function of distance. I would be very glad for any answers.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8AmxzbhEQ_FaVFCOTlvcWNnWE0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I suggest you add some error messages or something.  It is hard to comment on this description alone.  Is your model similar to [this one](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/examples/automotive-suspension.html) (but for trains)?

Comment: A related question...does your model assume that the wheels are always in contact with the track?  I would assume so, but I just wanted to confirm.

Comment: this variation in the link has no error but system is all going down. Every single body has its own position vector when add component fixed then I get the singularity error

Comment: yes, wheels and track do not lose the contact

Comment: Are you really interested in 3D motion?  Or are you only concerned with the up and down motion of the suspension?

Comment: I am interested in 2d motion i.e, vertical motion and pitch of the car body by using multibody library if I can install the planar mechanics in the pc room of our chair I will try it

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet would be a library like this one:

https://github.com/dzimmer/PlanarMechanics